# I need a more efficient way to validate my first two characters in a string are letters, and the rest are numbers

Tags: java, validation, substring

So what i'm doing is creating a method that will validate that the sku meets my format requirement.  which is AA1234 (as long as the first two characters are letters, and the rest are numbers).

i'm stumped

```
if(sku.substring(0,1).!startsWhith('0'))|(sku.substring(0,1).!startsWith('1'))
```

and so on and so on, like this could go on FOR EVER... If any of you have seen my previous posts i'm relatively new to java, and was just introduced to methods this past week.  i've been on this one program all night, and this is just one component of it i'm having a hard time with.  My knowledge just isn't there and i'm limited to only what i've been taught and read.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Google for "regex" and "regex java". Or read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Also `Character.isLetter`/`isDigit`.

Comment: Have you looked at `Character.isDigit()` and `Character.isLetter()`?

Comment: *"My knowledge just isn't there and i'm limited to only what i've been taught and read ..."*  - My advice would be to read more.  At least, selectively.  For a start, read the javadocs for the String and Character classes.  And Pattern that String links to

Comment: yes, thank you, by using this i was able to do the validation necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try a [*regular expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) for two letters and the rest [digits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html), you might do

```
if (sku.matches("[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d+")) {
    // valid
}
```